# how to include an external Vue script in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

i am new in Vue.js and i have a question.
I have typed a Vue script (Methods) that i want to use in the other components of my App. so i put this code in a component between tow script tags but i dont know how to use the functions of this Vue script in my Vue App.

Any Ideas to do this ?

Thanks

```js
<script>
import axios from 'axios';
  export default {
    components:{
      'axios':axios
    },
    data:function(){
      return{
        info:" ",
        table:"",
        table_list:[]
      }

    },
    methods:{
      FetchData:function(table){
        axios
        .get('http://localhost/cgi-      bin/pbf%20functions%20generator/PBF%20Functions%20Generator%20API2.pl?table='+table)
        .then(response => (this.info = response.data))
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
      },
      tableList:function(){
        axios
        .get('http://localhost/cgi-bin/pbf%20functions%20generator/PBF%20Functions%20Generator%20API2.pl?type=list')
        .then(response => {return this.table_list = response.data})
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
      }

    },
    mounted(){
      this.tableList();
    }
  }

</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Vue mixins, wherein you can define your methods in a mixin file. This mixin will be mixed with the components methods.

File: mixins.js

```
var baseMixin = {
    methods: {
        getData: function (target) {
            axios.get('url'+table)
            .then(response => (this.info = response.data))
            .catch(error => console.log(error))
        }
    }
};
```

File: somecomponent.js

```
Vue.component('some-component', {
    props: ['users', 'roles'],
    mixins: [baseMixin],
    methods: {
        someMethod: function(){
            this.getData
        }
    }
});
```

Also the Vue documentation explains it very well [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html)